# logrotate - truncate log file at 5 Mb, delete the rest of the log file

Tags: logrotate

Here is my script:

```
/var/log/libbitcoin/*.log {
    size 5M
    missingok
    rotate 0
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 644 bs bs
    sharedscripts
}
```

For some reason it is creating debug.log.1 whereas I just want it to delete the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you run `logrotate -d /path/to/your/config/above`?

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't know about this option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running with `-d` shows that there is a conflict due to `delaycompress`, which says compress the last-but-one log, when `rotate 0` says there should be no such log.

Since you do not keep any old logs, simply remove the `compress` and `delaycompress` options.

Answer (score -1):

In following code you can see the files will be deleted after period of time depends on which cron job, you simply can modify it by adding size file to it

```
find /var/log -name "*.log-*" -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;

find /var/log -name "*.gz" -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```